# Is there a service for testing iPhone applications on different types of devices?

Tags: iphone

I have developed an iPhone app using an iPhone 3G. How can I test it on iPhone 3GS, iPad, etc.? Is there a service online that lets me access a 3GS or iPad remotely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To test on real different devices and not on an emulator (which in no way represents the actual on device behaviour/performance), you can use a very professional service of DeviceAnywhere. It's payed service though. (not sure about the pricing)

http://www.deviceanywhere.com/index.aspx?sid=6&ssid=65&nid=78&nid=65

Comment: hundreds of us, Apple Developers, shipped iPad versions of applications with not a single iPad on the market, all just using the fantastic iPhone Simulator that is part of the SDK, it works fine for 99% of the stuff, just the accelerometer need an actual device.

Comment: @balexandre As Reflog pointed out you should test on a real device, especially because of performance tests. Your Macs CPU is a bit faster than the iDevices...

Comment: for that, u should invest in a 2nd hand device for testing. the value get from one app is sufficient to get money for a 2nd hand device.

Answer (score 0):

just run the **iPhone Simulator** and change the Hardware **Device** to iPad

regarding iPhone versions, you can change that as well.

[alt text http://cl.ly/b64f8d928cdfda3e349e/content](http://cl.ly/b64f8d928cdfda3e349e/content)